# If $f(y)-f(\bar{x})\geq v\cdot (y-\bar{x})$ then $v = \nabla f(\bar{x})$

Tags: analysis, optimization

How to show that if f, continuously differentiable function is defined over an open convex space $U$ of $R^n$, and if it exists $\bar{x}$ and $v$ such that $\forall y\in U, f(y)-f(\bar{x})\geq v\cdot (y-\bar{x})$ then $v = \nabla f(\bar{x})$ ?

So far I have showed that $\nabla f(\bar{x}) \geq v$ with the fact that $f(\bar{x}+h_i)-f(\bar{x}) \geq v_i$ but I don't know how to prove the other inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it : considering the function f(x)-v.x then $\bar{x}$ is a mimimum. We get what we want with the first order condition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community bot, his answer is correct. No need for checking anything. The only thing left here is he accepting his own answer. =)